# What can i add so my progra waits for the answer?

Tags: c#, serial-port, com-port

I have a pair of com ports.one of them sends data and the other one reads data. I want it to send a command (p) automatically every five seconds and wait to get the answer and read it and the sends the command again. Now it just sends the command automatically every 5 seconds. I don't know what to add to wait for the answer...

```
private Timer _timer;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _timer = new Timer();
    _timer.Interval = 5000;
    _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
}
private void _timer_Tick(object sender , EventArgs e)
{
    SendData();
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnSendData.PerformClick();
}
private void btnSendData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_timer.Enabled)
    {
        SendData();
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        _timer.Enabled = false;
    }
}
private void SendData()
{
    if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
    {
        dataOut = "P<CR>";
        serialPort1.Write(dataOut);
    }
}
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    dataIn = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(ShowData));
}
private void ShowData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tBoxDataIn.Text += dataIn;
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to wait? after the write action?

Comment: after it sends the command and reads the answer   @JeroenvanLangen

Comment: Does the `serialPort1_DataReceived` not work?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen   no its ok..i just want to know how the program understands that it doesn't have to send the command again until it receives data... I don't know the code and where to add it.

Comment: You can resend the command in the `ShowData` method

Answer (score -2):

I think this will be helpful:

- [async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async)
- [await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await)

Using async to create a task and then awaiting it is the way to go i think.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).